Pathfinding with hector_slam
I am currently using hector_slam on my surface vehicle and I need to navigate it through an unknown set of obstacles. I need to implement a dynamic pathfinding algorithm that will take the vehicle from its starting position (0, 0) to (0, 25), for example.
I don't need to actually control the vehicle, I only need the path in coordinates.
What are some of the pathfinding packages I can use to make it work?
